# Structure basic data in Firebase (Product, brands and categories)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning Firebase (Firestore) and React. Previously, i've worked with PostgreSQL and Rails, so everything looks different to me. I've read a lot about how to use it, and i am able to get data, store simple data etc. but i'm pretty much totally losted on how to structure my data and work with it correctly. I understand there is not "one way only" to do it, but could someone explain me, as if you're talking to a real beginner, how to structure the following data for example ?

I have products. Each product have a name, a price, a brand and somme sellers (online shops that sells the product).
Each brand can have a name, a website and many products associated.
Each seller can have a name, a website and many products associated.

From what i've read, it looks like i should structure it like this : a Products collection, a Brands collection and a Sellers collection. Here is what it looks like in my Firestore console :

Products collection
[image: products collection]

Brands collection
[image: brands collection]

Brands - products subcollection
[image: Brands - products subcollection]

Sellers collection
[image: sellers collection]

The seller subcollection looks like the brands - products subcollection.

First question : **Does this structure makes sense ?**
Second question : **As i've used references in my data, how can i access for example 'brand' or 'sellers' from each product ?**

Right now, i've created the following function in my react component to get all my products :

```
getAllProducts() {
    productsCollection
      .orderBy('releaseDate', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const products = firebaseLooper(snapshot);
          const brand = '';
          const sellers = [];

          console.log(doc.data());

          this.setState({
            products,
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

When i `console.log(doc.data());`, i can see all my data correctly. But how do i access the brand values and sellers values in a readable format ? Right now, it looks like this :

[image: console.log(doc.data())]

So i can't use `doc.data().brand` for example.

What i'm trying to achieve is a simple app where you have a form to add a new product. You add a name, a price, select a brand and sellers. In the product page, you can see the name, the price, the brand and the seller(s) associated with the product.

EDIT : Here is what the firebaseLooper function looks like :

```
export const firebaseLooper = (snapshot) => {
  let data = [];

  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    data.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    });
  });

  return data;
};
```

Comment: In order to model your data effectively with NoSQL databases like Firestore, you first have to determine what you want your specific queries to be.  Just knowing the project requirements and data relationships isn't enough.  Without knowing the queries, you are just putting data into a database with no purpose.  Please edit the question to explain what your desired queries are.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I've edited my question and added some code / screenshots so it's clearer!